# Is it considered anti-pattern resolve promises in React Component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In many places of the app we do call a `/search` api where you pick the id from of the result and the then the result will be discarded, Since the results are for temporal use, this makes me feel it's not worth to save them or even to dispatch actions (except to set a isLoading flag). But it will force me to resolve the promises in react components, is it considered bad practice or anti-pattern?

eg:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.doSearch(criterias)
      .then(res => this.setState({ results: res.results }) )
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a known anti-pattern in ReactJS, because you can't guarantee that the component will still exist when the promise resolves. You can technically check using this.isMounted, but that's also considered an anti-pattern.

The problem is that ReactJS isn't really designed to be a full-on application framework - you're kind of shoving MVC into it when really it's only a V. To be most effective, React should be paired with some other library (Redux is very popular) which can store the application data, then React can present it for you. It's best to think of React as a library which turns the internal UI state into an actual UI. It's not good for managing state.

See https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I know react is intented for View that's why I asked this question. my question arise because I feel, fetch, save in store, once user pick the id, I will have to empty that slice of the store again, since it's temporal, maybe there is other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is an anti-pattern in React. It's possible that `this.setState({ results: res.results })` will be executed after the component unmounted.

The best way is move the state (search pending/search resolved) out of react component. You can take advantage of `redux`+`redux-thunk` or `mobx` or `flux` to help you. For simple case, you can build a cancellable promise.

```
const makeCancelable = (promise) => {
  let hasCanceled_ = false;

  const wrappedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    promise.then(
      val => hasCanceled_ ? reject({isCanceled: true}) : resolve(val),
      error => hasCanceled_ ? reject({isCanceled: true}) : reject(error)
    );
  });

  return {
    promise: wrappedPromise,
    cancel() {
      hasCanceled_ = true;
    },
  };
};

class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.cancellableSearch = makeCancelable(this.props.doSearch());
    this.cancellableSearch.then((res) => {
      this.setState({ results: res.results });
    }).catch((reason) => {
      if (!isCanceled.isCanceled) {
        console.error('some error occurs', reason);
      }
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.cancellableSearch.cancel();
  }

  // ...
}
```

Cancellable promise code is copied from here: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Comment: I indeed using redux in our project. the problem of putting in store is, now for every place I call search api, I would have to save the result in different slice of the store and feel it's redundant since once you pick the id, you not longer need the results